# Authorize.Net ARB Api getting Timed out

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, sandbox, authorize.net

I am setting up a authorized.net payement gateway for my website. I'm currently doing a sandbox payement. I send an xml to the API call https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api.but I'm getting following error:

```
* About to connect() to apitest.authorize.net port 443 (#0)
* Trying 64.94.118.152...
* Timeout
* connect() timed out!
* Closing connection #0
```

But I'm getting it correct on my localhost.. I'm getting this error when I move it to test server..
What could be the issue?? Any ideas and suggestions would be helpful..thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked your connection log for details on why the connection is failing?

Comment: @rhldr thanks for replay..it was a server issue..i moved it to another server and now it is working fine...thank u